# how to get rid of all the hammers in Qtcreator's "Projects" view

Tags: qt-creator

The image shows the "Projects" sidebar of Qtcreator after opening&configuring a new project from its `CMakeLists.txt.` I am surprised by the many entries with a hammer icon. What do they stand for, where do they come from, and most importantly how to get rid of them?

Versions:

- Qt Creator 4.3.1 based on Qt 5.9.2
- cmake version 3.9.5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of them put a checkmark on `Hide Generated Files` in `Filter Tree` menu:

[image]

They come with CTest in CMakeLists.txt:

```
include(CTest) # equivalent to "enable_testing() ???
```

They stand for various CTest build targets, they are added automatically as soon as CTest is enabled for the project. You can also see them from command line:

```
$ ctest -D help
CTest -D called with incorrect option: help
Available options are:
  ctest -D Continuous
  ctest -D Continuous(Start|Update|Configure|Build)
  ctest -D Continuous(Test|Coverage|MemCheck|Submit)
  ctest -D Experimental
  ctest -D Experimental(Start|Update|Configure|Build)
  ctest -D Experimental(Test|Coverage|MemCheck|Submit)
  ctest -D Nightly
  ctest -D Nightly(Start|Update|Configure|Build)
  ctest -D Nightly(Test|Coverage|MemCheck|Submit)
  ctest -D NightlyMemoryCheck
```

Further info: https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest

Comment: Sounded really promising ... but didn't work for me.

Comment: My qtcreator version differs in that my `Filter Tree` menu has only two entries, `Simplify Tree` and `Hide Generated Files`. `Hide Empty Directories` is absent.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke hmm.. why not just upgrade? :)

Comment: @JoachimWuttke I can't even figure out how to download your version

Comment: Why not just upgrade? - because generally I prefer to stay with packets from my Linux distribution. If I start compiling this or that software on my own, then sooner or later I will run into other troubles.